# "calling myself all the asses heads in the world"

Tags: meaning

> On the instant of his departure, which I noted, a bright star or
>   vapour leaped forth above his head (as though he had heaved up his
>   sword), and broke all about in fire. The cocks crowed midnight through
>   the valley, and I sat me down by the mill-wheel, chewing spearmint
>   (though that's an herb of Venus), **and calling myself all the asses'
>   heads** in the world! 'Twas plain enough now!'

This is from "A DOCTOR'S MEDICINE" by Kipling.
https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/k/kipling/rudyard/rewards/index.html

I am glad if someone kindly teach me the meaning below
"calling myself all the asses heads in the world"
**strong text**

Answer (score 2):

Historically, "asses' head" is a metaphor for "slow-witted" or "stupid".  "All the X in the world" is simply a colorful way to exemplify whatever X is, and essentially means "extremely".

Put it together, and Kipling's Mr. Culpeper is saying that he felt *extremely stupid* for not realizing the answer sooner.

Neither of these expressions is, I think, in common use today.   Instead we might say something like:

> I felt like the biggest idiot in the world

By the way (in case it's not clear) "ass" means "donkey".  Again, historically, the ass was used as a metaphor for stupidity or foolishness. Today calling someone an "ass" more likely means they are rude and/or annoying (at least in AmE).

Comment: Indeed, the OED attests "ass" meaning "fool" since the 16th century (still found: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ass ) and "ass-head" from the same period (found in Shakespeare).  These uses derive from "ass" meaning a donkey, although in the US if you called someone an ass they would probably assume it was a vulgar usage.

Comment: Andrew, thank you so much for your kind and detailed answer!